# How to set input field value using Symfony 5 + Panther + Webbrowser + Chrome + setValue + Hmtl + Js

Tags: webbrowser-control, chromium, symfony5, setvalue, symfony-panther

how to set in basic-regular controller not TestController which is extended from TestCase, set to input field on Web text value?

```
    public function automatical_login_with_codes()
{
    $browser = new HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create());
    $client = Client::createChromeClient();
    $jsLink     = "document.querySelector('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxOpenLogin').click()";
    $crawler    = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.best.com/CategoryList.aspx?');
    $client->executeScript($jsLink);
    $client->waitFor('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxLoginText');//        $this->assertSame
    $crawler->filter('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxLoginText')->text('USERNAME'); <<-- NOT SET :(((
$check = $crawler->filter('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxLoginText')->text();
dd($check);  //<- result nothing
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is very simple (I simulate typing in browser input field value - USERNAME)

```
$crawler->filter('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxLoginText')->sendKeys('USERNAME');
```

Hope it save your time :)

Comment: Is there a way to reset the field ? Because `sendKeys()` seems to append content to the input

Comment: Maybe sendKeys('') would work, try it

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
$client->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#ctl00_uxAuthenticationBlock_uxLoginText'))->sendKeys('USERNAME');
```